# What is the executable /usr/bin/host on linux good for? Can I kill it?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, malware, hosts

So I had a compromised **/usr/bin/host** process running and trying to open HTTP requests out of my machine. I killed it. But now I am wondering. Do I need /usr/bin/host for anything? How do I re-install it? I am on Ubuntu.

1000 thanks!

Answer (score 1):

/usr/bin/host is a DNS lookup utility.

I doubt anyone can definitively say you need it or don't, it will depend on what you are running.   I'm pretty sure its a core package so you should have it - that said, the system should run at least mostly fine without it.

That said, according to [this thread](http://forums.cpanel.net/f185/suspicious-process-usr-bin-host-run-users-server-396312.html) the problem may be worse then you think, in as much as it may not be /usr/bin/host that is trojaned it may well be the underlying shared library its calling.    You should also question if an attacker has been able to overwrite /usr/bin/host - in which case you can't trust the system.   The ownership files on this are that it can only be written by root - which means they probably have own your box (and you don't).   Sorry, but best practice dictates a reinstall of the box.